# Translation of 曲がりたくても

Tags: translation

I have the following translation.

```
名古屋市内に入ると、
工事中で、
一方通行が多くて、
曲がりたくてもまっすぐ行かなければなりませんでした。
```

The following is what I have so far.

```
When I arrived inside the City of Nagoya
it was under construction and
there was a lot of 1 way traffic and
... I had to go straight.
```

I think `曲がりたくて` is the te-form of `曲がりたい` (I want to turn). But I am not sure how the following `も` connects it to the second part of the sentence. The only te-form + も structure we've learned is permission (followed by `いいですか` or something similar).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

〜ても means something like "even if".

> 曲がりたくてもまっすぐ行かなければなりませんでした。
>   "Even if I wanted to turn, I had no choice but to go straight."

Comment: Could it mean "even though"?

Comment: Interesting question. No, I think that'd be more like 曲がりたかったのに、…

Comment: You want "though" to get away from the fact that "if" sounds hypothetical... maybe "even when", then? This ても doesn't have to be a total hypothetical. The writer almost certainly **did** find himself wanting to turn. Yet it is different from "even though(のに)". "Even though(のに)" would seem to imply there was **one** (long, persisting?) time he wanted to turn. "Even if/when(ても)" on the other hand implies that he was forced to go straight on all occasions, even including the (possibly **many**) occasions when he wanted to turn.

Comment: Thanks @Hyperworm. That was what I was trying to get at (a more fluid sounding sentence). I wonder if "even if I had wanted" sounds a bit better and is still a straightforward translation?

Comment: Though I guess that would have to be `曲がりたくていても` huh?